# Как зафиксировать дочернее субменю при прокрутке родительского субменю

Tags: javascript, jquery, список, меню, mousewheel

Есть у меня меню с субменю. Суть такая, что при прокрутке родительского субменю(второе) прокручивается дочернее(третье) субменю.

1. Как можно зафиксировать дочернее субменю при прокрутке родительских субменю.
2. Как зафиксировать родительское субменю при прокрутке дочернего.
3. Как при прокрутке добавить стрелку вверх и вниз в зависимости от того есть скроллинг или нет

https://jsfiddle.net/cd8cf7yd/

```
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').children().click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});


$(function () {
    $('.parent').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        var course = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var top = parseInt($('.parent').css('top'));
        if (course > 0) {
            /*console.log("Scroll UP");*/
            $('.parent').css({
                'top': (top + 20) + 'px'
            });
        } else if (course < 0) {
            /*  console.log("Scroll DOWN");*/
            $('.parent').css({
                'top': (top - 20) + 'px'
            });
        }
        /* console.log($('.parent').css('top'));*/
    })
})


$('ul li').hover(function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}, function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});


$('.par>li').mouseenter(function () {

    $('.parent').css("top", '0');
});
```

Comment: Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, пожалуйста пометьте ответ, вопросы без ответов со временем удаляются, а значит ответы не помогут людям в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

В коде есть комментарии и все что вам непонятно можно уточнить так что я просто отвечу на каждый вопрос и приведу листинг кода.

1. Как можно зафиксировать дочернее субменю при прокрутке родительских субменю. **Перевернуть знак его** "top" **свойства**
2. Как зафиксировать родительское субменю при прокрутке дочернего. **Не позволять событию прокрутки достигать родительского элемента. [Прочитать подробнее можно здесь.](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)**
3. Как при прокрутке добавить стрелку вверх и вниз в зависимости от того есть скроллинг или нет. **В коде есть проверка на границы прокрутки, вы можете использовать эту проверку для добавления этого функционала**

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/cd8cf7yd/6/)

```
var log = console.log;

$('.child').hide();

$('.parent').children().click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});


$(function () {
  var container = $('.container');
    var parent = $('.parent');
    parent.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
      /* Тут происходит магия, мы не даем событию скрола поднятся до обработчика который мы написали выше. Что бы понять как это работает, прочтите про всплытие событий в JS */
    event.stopPropagation();
      /* Мы уже находимся в области видимости элемента $('.parent') нет необходимости получать jquery объект снова. К нему можно обратиться через this*/
        var $this = $(this);
        /* Высота родителя минус высота контейнера, перевовариваем знак по тому что высота в отрицательных значениях */
        var scrollHeight = ($this.outerHeight() - container.height()) * (-1);
        var course = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || (event.originalEvent.detail * -1);
        var top = parseInt($this.css('top'));
        /* Находим все дочерние элементы, если вам принципиально иметь класс .parent2 вы можете добавить его как еще один класс, в текущей реализации в нем нет необходимости*/
        var children = $this.find('.parent');

        if (course > 0) top += 20;
        else top -= 20;

        if (course > 0) {
          /*console.log("Scroll UP");*/

            /* Добавляем ограничение скрола сверху*/
            /* Собственно, если вы разберетесь с тем что я здесь сделал, то можно расширить необходимый вам функционал из 3 пункта. Аналогично и для скрола вниз*/
          $this.css({
                'top': (top < 0) ? top : 0
            });
            children.css({
                'top': (top < 0) ? -top : 0
            });
        } else {
          /*console.log("Scroll DOWN");*/

          /* Добавляем ограничение скрола снизу*/
            $this.css({
                'top': (top > scrollHeight) ? top : scrollHeight
            });
            children.css({
                'top': (top > scrollHeight) ? -top : -scrollHeight
            });
        }
        /* console.log($('.parent').css('top'));*/
    })
})


$('ul li').hover(function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}, function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});


$('.par>li').mouseenter(function () {

    $('.parent').css("top", '0');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо.
1. Но не хочет работать в Firefox.
2. Как при клике на кнопки up и down чтобы был скроллинг блока